# Адаптация html шаблона под joomla 2.5

Tags: шаблоны, joomla, html

Имеется шаблон (обычный html), можно ли (и как) его адаптировать под joomla 2.5?

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: Как минимум нужны прямые руки!

Comment: @jkwe45, если честно, то вопрос из разряда: "Есть видеокамера. Можно ли снять на неё фильм?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните отсюда: [User%3ARvsjoen/tutorial/Developing a Template/Part 01](http://docs.joomla.org/User%3ARvsjoen/tutorial/Developing_a_Template/Part_01). Если сложно, то посмотрите о структуре шаблона: [Создание макета шаблона](http://j-wiki.ru/Joomla/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) (правда 1.6).

Comment: @co11ter, "Начните отсюда" ссылка на эту же страницу?

Comment: Странно... Проверил, ссылка верная, но хешкод почему-то по ней не ходит(( Продублирую http://docs.joomla.org/User:Rvsjoen/tutorial/Developing_a_Template/Part_01

Comment: @co11ter, я задал вопрос по поводу этого бага [сюда](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/179/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0 "Ссылка ведёт на туже страницу на которой указана "), надеюсь с этим разберутся...

Comment: UPD я задал вопрос на форум Мета: http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/179/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: @co11ter решил проблему с ':' надо вместо него в URL использовать %3A

Comment: Всё, исправил.